# How do I get the text of the element using xpath and python?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

I am having A LOT of trouble getting elements in the webpage using xpath. I need to get the text on the left as well as the right. [image] There are 7 classes, so there will be 7 of these. [image]

Within these divs this is what it looks like [image]

I just need the text which corresponds to the first photo.
Below is just ONE attempt

```
result = session_requests.get(url, headers = dict(referer = url))
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
grades = tree.xpath(".//div[@class='AssignmentClass'][1]//text()")
print grades
```

Comment: Which text? the text within the <a> tag? the whole div dom?

Comment: The text within the <a> tag but if you look at the comments of the below answer we established that result.content does not contain the div 'AssignmentClass'

Comment: For dynamically generated content you could use selenium+phantomjs/Firefox or Splash. If you're looking for speed take a look at scrapyJS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following XPath

1. To get the text from the `<a>` tags:

   ```
   //div[@class='AssignmentClass']//a/text()
   ```
2. To get the text from the `<span>` tags:

   ```
   //div[@class='AssignmentClass']//span[2]/text()
   ```

Comment: Sorry I was referring to when you do tree.findall. But this is what I do and I still get [] `grade = tree.xpath("//div[@class='AssignmentClass']//a/text()")`

Comment: I completley understand what you are saying, but when I run the 1st line of code you provided I get a nil still. When you do //a is that selecting the `a` tag?

Comment: @user6032625 - If you simply use `//div[@class='AssignmentClass']` does this fetch all the 7 `div`'s?

Comment: No still prints nil.

Comment: @user6032625 - Check the `result.content` and see if it is the same as source you see on the browser.

Comment: Yup I do not see `AssignmentClass` div. Everything printed in the console is in the browser, but not the other way around. Why is that?

Comment: There must be some JavaScript code executing which makes some DOM manipulations to add /modify data visible on the page. You'll have to use `selenium-webdriver` in this case. Using `requests` won't suffice.

Comment: There is indeed a JavaScript code being executed to do exactly that. Is selenium-webdriver the only way? How would I do that?

Comment: @user6032625 - You can have a look at this [tutorial](http://thiagomarzagao.com/2013/11/12/webscraping-with-selenium-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Xpath is so powerful because it's a syntax for describing both a daatapath and the data itself.

In this case, you would end your path with `text()` because that's what you want.

`tree.xpath(".//div[@class='AssignmentClass'][1]//text()")`

Comment: I still get [], I have updated the question with more code.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to use this to get the the title http://puu.sh/oGPhT/7457770ef3.png